# Stop the delete button from sending user back a page

Tags: javascript, keystroke

My current web application gets the key press of the user, however, if the user hits the delete or backspace button it sends the user back a page. Is their a way of preventing this?

Comment: Why your application sendes th user a page back  if the user hits the delete or backspace?

Comment: no it doesn't send them back. I think it is a default setting on browsers for if some element isn't focused and they hit the back button it will automatically send them back a page.

Comment: @juhana Yes it does, I know older version of IE definitely do this. Current versions of Chrome do as well.

Comment: even the latest version of google chrome does it.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes this easy. You can easily replace this with vanilla JS and use `addEventListener()` for class A browsers and `attachEvent()` for legacy IE, and normalize `keyCode` and `charCode` yourself. But why?

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    var keycode =  e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;    
    if(keycode == 46){ // delete
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The backspace key `keyCode 8` is detectable from within a focused input only and will likely still emit your undesired behavior, but it'll keep the user happy.

Here is a complete list of [keyCodes](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)